# ListView item stays highlighted

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an app which uses two fragments. One of the fragments uses a ListView to display items and when clicked, the second fragment updates itself (it is a dictionary app).
Once an item is selected in the ListView, I want it to be highlighted. I achieved this by using the following properties in XML file for ListView item.

```
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

This works fine as far as selection of the item is concerned. But the problem is when I scroll the list, the selection sometimes stays on the at the bottom or top of the list (as the case may be) even though the selected item is not present in the list. Here are screenshots to explain my problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The first pic shows no selection; in second pic, I selected 101 and hence second fragment was updated. In the third pic, even though 101 is not shown, a part of the ListView is highlighted.

What's the issue ?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Here is the OnItemClick() method.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

    String selectedWord = words.get(arg2); //words in an ArrayList which holds all the words displayed in this fragment.

    Meaning meaningFragment = (Meaning) getSupportFragmentManager().
                                         findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentMeaning);
    meaningFragment.searchMeaning(selectedWord); //this method updates the other fragment.
}
```

**EDIT:**

This problem is not resolved yet. I have uploaded the project on [github](https://github.com/addresseerajat/ListViewTest) if anyone wants to have a look.

Comment: can you provide the onItemClick() method please.

Comment: have you tried looking at the example provided with eclipse. There is a master-detail example with left-pane updating right-pane details and it just works fine.

Comment: show us your getView method

Comment: @LenaBru: Currently I am not using a Customized Adapter, I am using a default ArrayAdapter for the ListView.

Comment: @HpTerm: Can you tell me sample from which API you are talking about. I will look into the sample project.

Comment: try overriding the onscroll method, and when you begin scrolling, give it "set

Comment: @HpTerm: Yeah that worked fine. But once I changed the selector color by calling `getListView().setSelector(R.color.color);`, same problem surfaced. The selection stays on screen.

Comment: ok so this is another question. do an update of your question, saying it is solved according to my answer and now you have another problem.

Comment: Where are you calling getListView().setSelector(R.color.color) in which method ?

Comment: Ok so my answer is useless. You say the example is more or less the same. Put your effort in looking carefully at the "more or less". Because a subtle difference could be the point. So, to be able to able you you should provide your full layout file and your nearly full code of the fragments so we could test it on our computers.

Comment: @HpTerm In case you want to have a look at the code and test it on your computer, I have uploaded the code on github. Here is the link: https://github.com/addresseerajat/ListViewTest
I have tried various modifications of the code, but none worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse you can create a Master-Detail Flow which is an example of what you are trying to do.

For this create a "New Android Application" and in the third or forth screen which is called "Create Activity", three possibilities are offered to you, select the one called "Master/Detail".

This does not provide an answer to your question but is just pointing you to a working example where you can elaborate from.

Now for the answer to your question, I looked at your code and found the mistake.

Here is the working code for the `onCreateView()`. I commented out the wrong lines of code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    //listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
    //          android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array));
    //listView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, array));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            listView.setItemChecked(position, true);
            FragmentTwo frag = (FragmentTwo) getActivity()
                                             .getFragmentManager()
                                             .findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentTwo);
            frag.updateTextView(array[position]);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

In your code the 2 following lines are wrong

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, array));
listView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
```

what you do here is set a `simple_dropdown_item_1line` which is not what you want and you manually set the `selector`.

You have to use `simple_list_item_activated_1` and not set the selector manually.

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, array));
//listView.setSelector(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
```

If you want a custom selector color, you can create a custom selector by copying the `simple_list_item_activated_1` and editing it to your needs and calling the edited layout.
However I recommend using the default colors so the day Android decides to change its color scheme you will be compliant to the new one.

In summary, to have the `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` working, you have to use `simple_list_item_activated_1` and not manually set the `selector`.